# Create a temporary certificate manually

Tags: .net, windows-8, certificate, microsoft-metro

I would like to create a temporary certificate (required for build a metro app) by command prompt. I had try to do this with CMD :

```
makecert.exe -n "CN=MY_DOMAIN" -r -a sha1 -sv MY_DOMAIN.pvk MY_DOMAIN.cer –ss root

pvk2pfx -pvk MY_DOMAIN.pvk -spc MY_DOMAIN.cer -pfx MY_DOMAIN.pfx
```

But when I this pfx file in my project, I have the following error :

> C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\AppxPackage\Microsoft.AppXPackage.Targets(1142,9):
>   error : APPX0107 : the specified certificate is not valid for signing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Three changes:

1. The certificate lacks the Code Signing OID (1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.3) in the Enhanced Key Usage extension. Add it using the `-eku 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.3` argument to `makecert`.
2. Place the certificate into the `My` certificate store rather than the root certificate store by replacing `-ss root` with `-ss My`.
3. Ensure the certificate is an end entity in the Basic Constraints extension using the `-cy end` argument to makecert.

See MSDN [Signing an app package (Windows Store apps)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br230260%28v=vs.110%29) for more information on signing Windows Store apps and [MakeCert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa386968%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for more information on makecert arguments.

Comment: Thank your for your fast anwser, but the problem is the same, even if I install the certificate, I have the same error.

Thank again :-)

Comment: @EtienneBaudoux I have added a not about placing the certificate into the `My` store rather than the `Root` store.

Comment: Thank again. It's look better because the certificate is now automatically installed in personal category of certificates library. But, there is always the same error =/

Comment: @EtienneBaudoux Delete the old certificate(s) from the Root certificate store (anything with a matching subject), recreate the PFX file and reference that in the code.

Comment: @EtienneBaudoux I have expanded the answer further and added a link to the MS site with more information.

Comment: Always the same error. Even if I uninstall all certificates and files concerned before makecert. I don't really know where the problem is. If I use a pfx file create with Visual Studio, it run. If my pfx file have no password, is it important for this problem?
I have already see this pages, but I havn't found any solutions.

Note : in certmgr.msc, in the role column, my certificate has not the same that a certificate created with Visual Studio (<All>). May be it can help?

Comment: @EtienneBaudoux Definitely try it without a password because MSBuild has no way to prompt the user for a password.

Comment: Ok, it is what I do since I started to make a certificate by command prompt. :-)

Comment: It's me again ! It works ! Thank you very much ! I havn't seen that you have changed the -eku argument in your message. So I have change the last number (2) by 3, and it run. Thank again ! Have a nice day :-)

Comment: @EtienneBaudoux There was a copy and paste error in the original answer. Sorry about that. Good to know it worked out.